# Python read a txt file into a list of lists of numbers

Tags: python

My txt file looks like this:

```
[[1,3,5],[1,4,4]]
[[1,4,7],[1,4,8],[2,4,5]]
```

And I was trying to convert it into a list, which include all the lists in the txt file. So the desired output for my example would be:

```
[[[1,3,5],[1,4,4]], [[1,4,7],[1,4,8],[2,4,5]]]
```

It seems like an easy task, except that I could only get this:

```
['[[1,3,5],[1,4,4]]', '[[1,4,7],[1,4,8],[2,4,5]]']
```

Is there an easy way to convert the string type into a list?

---

The code I used :

```
input_list = []
with open("./the_file.txt", 'r') as f:
    lines = f.read().split('\n')
    for each_line in lines:
        input_list.append(each_line)

f.close()
```

Comment: `with open("./the_file.txt", 'r') as f: answer = [ast.literal_eval(line.strip()) for line in f]`

Comment: Do you want the list items to be represented as integers or strings?

Comment: @JohnGordon Integers. Sorry that I didn't make it clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You really want to evaluate each line in your file as actual python code. However, doing so can be problematic (e.g.: what happens if one line says `import os; os.system('rm -rf /')`).

[So you don't want to use something like `eval`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15197673/198633) for this

Instead, you might consider using `ast.literal_eval`, which has a few safeguards against this sort of behavior:

```
with open("./the_file.txt", 'r') as f:
    answer = [ast.literal_eval(line.strip()) for line in f]
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in one line with `ast.literal_eval` and a list comprehension:

```
from ast import literal_eval

input_list = [literal_eval(line) for line in open("./the_file.txt", 'r') ]
```

Comment: You're safer with `ast.literal_eval`, which will prevent you from accidentally blowing up your computer, for instance

Comment: Thanks, amended my code.

Answer (score 0):

If your lines in the text file are well formatted, you can use [eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval).

```
input_list.append(eval(each_line))
```